# How to open file 'libboost_thread-vc110-mt-gd-1_58.lib' - cpp-netlib?

Tags: c++, boost, cpp-netlib

So I'm almost a complete newbie to c++. I've been trying desperately for the better part of the day to use [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/latest/getting_started.html#getting-started), but I can't really proceed, and would appreciate some help.

I have downloaded the development version as per the instructions (I assume that's what I need to be able to use the library), and am not building it, as the instructions specify that it's only required if I want to run the test suite.

I have downloaded the latest Boost and built it (from the command line).

**Now when I try a sample application, I get a linker error saying "cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc110-mt-gd-1_58.lib".**

The include and linker directories have been set up. I've peeked inside relevant folder, and only libboost_thread files are all VC 120, which from what I understand means they've been generated by a different version of Visual Studio.

I don't really know what to do next.

*If it helps, I'm using visual Studio 2012.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the directory where that library is located in your pc in the libpath of the Visual Studio project, as explained in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Done that. The problem is, that specific library doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you compiled boost thread module for Windows? If you don't want to compile it, you can find pre-compiled binaries including that library at [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/boost_1_58_0-msvc-11.0-64.exe/download).